# Python facebook windows app not allow

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My program download some infos about user and post it to the label in app.
I have a interaction/authorization problem with gui Facebook app in python. My app uses tkinter, facebook and fbconsole.

I autorized in this way.

```
import fbconsole as F
F.APP_ID="123"
F.AUTH_SCOPE=['publish_stream', 'publish_checkins', 'read_stream', 'offline_access']
F.ACCESS_TOKEN = "1234"
F.authenticate()
```

And something for show results

```py
newsfeed = F.get('/me/home', {'fields':'from,name,description,message'})
newsfeedData = newsfeed["data"]
label.config(text=newsfeedData)
```

But when I run it, appear new facebook tab in browser announce: "Application configuration does not allow the use of the URL". How can I get rid of it?
Thanks!

Comment: publish_stream, publish_checkins and offline_access doesn't exists anymore

Comment: It does not matter, even if I delete them, the pop up still appears

Comment: What redirect url are you using and what have you configured in the Developer app?

Comment: '/me/home' - (this is only one uri I use) link to myself to get posts from wall. In developer I have generated keys and token. That's all.